# CHROOT : Allowing outside access to chrooted users with mount bind

Tags: linux, bind, mount, chroot

I have a chrooted user(username: clientdev) which I have jailed inside their home directory. This chroot directory is /home/clientdev/ which is owned by root.

Now I need this clientdev user to be able access the tomcat web application folder which is residing under /mnt/datadrive/tomcat/webapps.

What I have done is :

1. chroot the user with a public key of their own to the home
   directory.
2. Create a folder under /home/clientdev called tomcat_ROOT and gave
   the ownership to clientdev.

Now when I run the command : 
 mount -bind /mnn/datadrive/tomcat/webapps /home/clientdev/tomcat_ROOT
 The folder disappears from the directory listing inside /home/clientdev if I login with clientdev. My root user can see it but now the desired user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance, 
 Peter

Output of `ls -l /home/clientdev/tomcat_ROOT`:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root   root    4096 Apr 11 15:07 .   
drwxrwxr-x. 12 root   root    4096 Apr 11 15:07 .. 
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root    4096 Apr  9 22:10 webapp1 
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root    4096 Mar 18 18:43 webapp2 
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root    4096 Apr  9 22:11 webapp3 
drwxrwxr-x. 10 root   root    4096 Apr 11 15:20 ROOT
```

Output of `ls -l /home/clientdev/`:

```
drwx------. 4 clientdev clientdev 4096 Apr 10 21:36 . 
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root      root      4096 Apr 10 22:07 .. 
-rw-------. 1 clientdev clientdev  664 Apr 10 21:43 .bash_history 
-rw-r--r--. 1 clientdev clientdev   18 Apr 23  2012 .bash_logout 
-rw-r--r--. 1 clientdev clientdev  176 Apr 23  2012 .bash_profile 
-rw-r--r--. 1 clientdev clientdev  124 Apr 23  2012 .bashrc 
drwx------. 2 clientdev clientdev 4096 Apr 10 19:20 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x. 2 clientdev clientdev 4096 Apr 10 21:34 tomcat_ROOT
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /home/clientdev/tomcat_ROOT`? BTW, you really ought to ask these kinds of questions on either https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x.  6 root   root    4096 Apr 11 15:07 .  
drwxrwxr-x. 12 root   root    4096 Apr 11 15:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root    4096 Apr  9 22:10 webapp1
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root    4096 Mar 18 18:43 webapp2
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root    4096 Apr  9 22:11 webapp3
drwxrwxr-x. 10 root   root    4096 Apr 11 15:20 ROOT`
I executed this command with the root user, since the client dev does not have access to this folder. + I apologize if I posted this in the wrong location. Thank you

Comment: Just edit that kind of thing into your question next time. It doesn't format well in the comments.

Comment: Now, what is the output of `ls -l /home/clientdev | grep tomcat_ROOT`?

Comment: Is there anything that I am doing wrong at the moment ?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the basic directory permissions. I recommend `su clientdev` from root shell to separate permissions issues from issues caused by security restrictions (like the jailed shell). (I mean just for looking around directories and testing now -- I don't recommend connecting the client like that always.)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, you are right, if I su clientdev, I am able to see the mounted directory and it works fine, but for some reason, it does not work when I use a public key and sftp with WINSCP - I do not see that folder under the home directory ... Thank you for your help so far